# Nexus upgrade from 2.x to 3.x is missing timestamp for the arifacts

Tags: nexus, nexus3

We are upgrading our nexus artifact repository from 2.x to 3.x version. During this process, after the migration is complete, there is a timestamp missing for the artifacts. Any solution regarding this will be helpful.

[image: nexus 2.x screenshot.]
[image: nexus 3.x screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your upgrade.  Tree view (browse) in Nexus Repository Manager 3 does not show last modified for folders.  I have never heard this requested but if this is important to you, suggest you file a ticket in issues.sonatype.com in the NEXUS project and it can be evaluated by the team.

Comment: Thanks @joedragons. I have raised a story for the same. 
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-24302